# Undecidable problem intersection of two DCFL languages is DCFL?

Tags: context-free, proof-techniques, pushdown-automata, pumping-lemma

We have two deterministic pushdown automatas A and B, which languages are deterministic context-free. The problem is to decide if there exists a deterministic pushdown automata, which language is an intersection of the languages of A and B. This problem is known to be undecidable. But I can't find a proof for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem statement**

We have two deterministic pushdown automatas (`DPDA`) $D_1$ and $D_2$. The problem is to decide whether there exists a `DPDA` $D$ such that $L(D) = L(D_1) \cap L(D_2)$.

**Post correspondence problem**

The proof is based on the fact that [Post correspondence problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_correspondence_problem) (`PCP`) is undecidable. Suppose we have a `PCP` problem with two input lists $\alpha = (\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n)$ and $\beta = (\beta_1, ..., \beta_n)$

**Define languages**

Let $$L = \{i_1...i_k\#j_m...j_1\$\beta_{j_1}...\beta_{j_m}\$\alpha_{i_k}^R...\alpha_{i_1}^R | \;1 \leq i_l \leq n, 1 \leq j_l \leq n \}$$ 
One can constructively show that there exists a DPDA $D_1$ that accepts $L$.
From the other hand, the language with words $u\$u^R\#v\$v^R$ also has DPDA $D_2$. Let's call this language $L_{rev}$.

Let intersection language be $L_{\cap} = L \cap L_{rev} $

**Emptiness of $L_{\cap}$ is equivalent to PCP decidability**

Consider a word from $L_{\cap}$. It is like $i_1...i_k\#j_m...j_1\$\beta_{j_1}...\beta_{j_m}\$\alpha_{i_k}^R...\alpha_{i_1}^R$ and like $u\$u^R\#v\$v^R$. So $\alpha_{i_1} = \beta_{i_1},..., \alpha_{i_k} = \beta_{i_k}.$

Since then, if $L_{\cap} \neq \varnothing$ then there is a solution for PCP. Otherwise, there is no solution.

**Emptiness of $L_{\cap}$ is equivalent to existing of $D$**

Furthermore if $L_{\cap} = \varnothing$ then $L_{\cap}$ has `DPDA` because it is empty.
Using pumping lemma, one can show that if $L_{\cap}$ is not empty then this language is not context-free. Since languages of `DPDAs` are subset of context-free languages then $D$ does not exist.

**Conclusion**

Assume we can decide if $D$ exists. Let's take our `PCP`, construct our languages and answer if $D$ exists. If it does exist, then the intersection language is empty and the `PCP` doesn't have a solution. Otherwise, it has. This way, we decide whether a solution for PCP exists. But this problem is known to be undecidable. We have come to a contradiction. Consequently, the assumption is wrong and the problem of deciding whether $D$ exists is undecidable.

Comment: I think there's something missing from this proof.  I think you have to prove that if $L_\cap$ is non-empty, then it is *not* a DCFL.  I don't see that argued here.  Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @D.W. thank you for your comment, I could take a look at the weekend