# Creating a Deterministic Push-Down Automaton for the Union of two languages

Tags: context-free, pushdown-automata

> Suppose, we have $L_1:=\{w\in\{a,b\}^*\mid \#_a(w) \equiv 0 \mod 4\}$ and $L_2:=\{w\in\{a,b\}^*\mid abaab \text{ is a substring of } w\}$. Now we want to create a Deterministic Push-Down Automaton for $L_1\cap L_2$

I've created PDA's for both languages:

$M'=(Q,\Sigma,\Gamma,\Delta,s,F)$ with $\Sigma=\{a,b\}$, $\Gamma=\{\}$, $Q=\{1,2,3,4\}$, $F=\{0\}$, $s=\{0\}$ and
\begin{align}
\Delta=\{&(0,a,\lambda,1,\lambda),(0,b,\lambda,0,\lambda)(1,a,\lambda,2,\lambda),(1,b,\lambda,1,\lambda),(2,a,\lambda,3,\lambda),(2,b,\lambda,2,\lambda)\\
&(3,a,\lambda,0,\lambda),(3,b,\lambda,3,\lambda)\}
\end{align}
where $\Delta\subseteq Q_{old}\times (\Sigma \cup \{\lambda\})\times(\Gamma\cup \lambda)\times Q_{new}\times\Gamma^*$

and

$M''=(Q,\Sigma,\Gamma,\Delta,s,F)$ with definitions above and $\Sigma=\{a,b\}$, $\Gamma=\{\}$, $Q=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, $F=\{6\}$, $s=\{1\}$ and
\begin{align}
\Delta=\{&(1,a,\lambda,2,\lambda),(1,b,\lambda,1,\lambda),(2,a,\lambda,2,\lambda),(2,b,3,\lambda),(3,a,\lambda,4,\lambda),(3,b,\lambda,1,\lambda),\\&(4,a,\lambda,5,\lambda),(4,b,\lambda,3,\lambda),(5,a,\lambda,2,\lambda),(5,b,\lambda,6,\lambda),(6,a,\lambda,6,\lambda),(6,b,\lambda,6,\lambda)\}
\end{align}

$M'$ accepts $L_1$ and $M''$ accepts $L_2$, but how to construct $M^{\star}=M'\cap M''$ which accepts $L_1\cap L_2$?

I know, that we could possibly do this with Deterministic Finite Automata, but I want to know how it would work with PDA's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general algorithm for computing a DPDA $M^*$ as the intersection of two DPDA $M,M'$; that problem is undecidable.  See [Undecidable problem intersection of two DCFL languages is DCFL?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/98355/755) for a proof.

So, you will have to look for some pattern in this particular problem that makes it easier than the general case.  Hint: what level in [the Chomsky hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy#The_hierarchy) is $L_1$ at?  what about $L_2$?

Comment: They're both type 3 and we possibly don't need the stack of the PDA to compute them. Unfortunately I should use PDA's to do it... We heard something of the Union of 2 PDA's that only works with a PDA that needs the Stack and one PDA for a language of type 3 which doesn't need the stack so you can mix them up. One does things on the stack and the other one just works like a DFA... But I'm not sure how to really apply this all in this particular case.

Comment: @Doesbaddel, great.  So you know they are type 3.  Could that be helpful?  This is your exercise, so you'll need to take it from here.  I suggest you spend some more time on it.

Comment: Yeah, I will try to do so. Can I use the algorithm for DFA's for intersection? Because both are of type 3 and then just change it to a PDA in the end?

Comment: I've created DEA's for both languages. After that I created the DEA for the intersection and then minimized it. Out of that I created a push down automata that doesn't use the stack.

Comment: @Doesbaddel, congratulations on solving the problem!  Nice job.